# Foursquare API Not returning photos on the Venue Search

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, api, foursquare

So I'm playing around with the Venues just trying to get it to show some stuff before I both getting specific with my queries.  I'm using nodejs and this module.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/foursquarevenues

If that matters.  Anyways when I put a call to the api to getVenues with a simple call like:

```
var params = {
        venuePhotos : '1',
        near : "Rome, Italy"
};
```

Everything works fine with the exception that no photos are returned.  A standard venue object from this call will look like this:

```
    id: '523b15ce11d2d66df7dca8d0',
    name: 'Qlub Radio, Roma',
    contact: {},
    location: 
     { lat: 41.891096,
       lng: 12.5106,
       labeledLatLngs: [Object],
       cc: 'IT',
       country: 'Italia',
       formattedAddress: [Object] },
    categories: [ [Object] ],
    verified: false,
    stats: { checkinsCount: 3, usersCount: 2, tipCount: 0 },
    venueRatingBlacklisted: true,
    beenHere: { lastCheckinExpiredAt: 0 },
    specials: { count: 0, items: [] },
    referralId: 'v-1493396577',
    venueChains: [],
    hasPerk: false }
```

Which as far as I can tell returns no photo url for the venue which is contrary to what the documentation suggests.  I've been putting in a bunch of different parameters as suggested in other threads and it hasn't changed anything.  Am I missing something here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the [node.js module you're using](https://github.com/elbuo8/4square/blob/master/lib/foursquareVenues.js) the `getVenues` call is hitting the Foursquare [venue/search](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) endpoint which doesn't return photos with the search results. Calling `exploreVenues` in that module will hit the [venues/explore](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/explore) endpoint which can return photos by including the `venuePhotos=1` parameter (as you've done).

Also, if you only details for a specific venue you can use `getVenue` and if you only need the photos you can use `getVenueAspect`.

Hope this helps.